# Creating a bijection between two ssets

Tags: combinatorics

Come up with ways that you can write a $6$ letter word with $3$ of the letters containing $U$ and $3$ of the letters containing $R$ such that there shall always be more $U's$ on the left side than $R's$.

So basically this means that we always need to start with $U$ and end with $R$

I found $5$ ways:

$1. UUURRR$

$2. URURUR$

$3. UURURR $

$4. URUURR$

$5. UURRUR $

Note: Hopefully the term left side isn't confusing. What i mean is if you look at $#2$, $URURUR$, if I put a point between the last $U$ and the last $R$, $URURU.R$, I would have three $U's$ to the left of the point and only two $R's$, so thats what I mean by more $U's$ on the left.

---

Now, list the number of ways to associate the letters $a,b,c,d$ under addition.
I was able to find 5 ways again:

$1. ((a+b)+(c+d))$

$2. (((a+b)+c)+d)$

$3. (a+(b+(c+d))) $

$4. ((a+(b+c))+d)$

### $5. (a+((b+c)+d))$

I was then asked to create a bijection between the letters and the association with letters and the bijection I came up with is:

Let $F$ be the function and if we input $U$ we get the parenthesis $($ and if we input $R$ we get $+$

so basically:

$$ U \rightarrow ( $$
$$ R \rightarrow + $$

---

This is true because  I can match them up.

So using the above:

$1. UUURRR \rightarrow (((a+b)+c)+d)$

Since $U=($ and $(((a+b)+c)+d)$ have three $($ and $R$ means $+$ and we have $3 +$, so it works.

I'll list the rest but if anyone needs me to explain, I will.

$2. URURUR \rightarrow (a+(b+(c+d)))$

$3. UURURR \rightarrow ((a+(b+c))+d)$

$4. URUURR \rightarrow (a+((b+c)+d))$

$5. UURRUR \rightarrow ((a+b)+(c+d))$

My real question is why do this bijection work?

Comment: "we always need to start with U and end with R"  I didn't get this interpretation at all.  RUURRU for instance has more U's than R's on the left side.

Comment: You could prove this is a bijection by induction on $n$, where $2n$ is the length of the string, or on $m$, where $m$ is the number of variables you're adding. A proof by induction might not answer your question of "why", but it would be a proof.

Comment: Basically aren't both sets both saying "we have three of one thing and three of the other and we start with one and end with the other-- these are all the possibilities and all possibilities is allowed"?

Comment: Your set has has 10 elements.  Your 5 plus RUUURR, RUURUR, RUURRU, UURRRU, URURRU.

Comment: @fleablood, i guess its kinda confusing what it means to the left side. What I mean is If I take your example: RUURRU and put a dot between the last R and U. So RUURR.U , from the left side of the dot there are 2 U's and 3 R's, but we cant have that since we need more U's on the left side.

Comment: Not sure why your bijection works, but if you consider the bijection $U\mapsto\mathord($ and $R\mapsto\mathord)$, it's fairly obvious why that one works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: I hope this helps. The following bijections will be easier to prove.

- Function $G: U~ \rightarrow~ ($ $~~~~$ and $~~~~$  $G: R~ \rightarrow ~)$
- Function $H: (~ \rightarrow~ ($ $~~~~$ and $~~~~$  $H: + ~\rightarrow ~)$

Combining them gives the required bijection.